# How can we use android:inputType in EditTextPreference?

Tags: android, xml, edittextpreference

I checked the documentation of EditTextPreference 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

But I failed to found the android:inputType attribute there. Then how it can be used in this code segment

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="edit"
        android:title="@string/location1"
        android:summary="@string/summary1"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/location1"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/message"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
```

Same doubt for the android:singleLine attribute.

Comment: Is android:summary ignored?  I cannot see where its used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditText, inputType values (XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712761/edittext-inputtype-values-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs don't list the attributes for that class, but the `InputType` attribute (and other `EditText` and `TextView` attributes) still work. It's only stated in the text. Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425338/how-to-set-only-numeric-value-for-edittextpreference-in-android).

The [`EditTextPreference` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html) doesn't explicitly list all the attributes it supports, but the text states:

> See [EditText Attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#EditText).

The link there isn't very useful (they probably reorganised some of the attributes but never updated some links to it), but here's a direct link to [inputType values](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType). As a quick summary those values are (as of the time of posting):

- none
- text
- textCapCharacters
- textCapWords
- textCapSentences
- textAutoCorrect
- textAutoComplete
- textMultiLine
- textImeMultiLine
- textNoSuggestions
- textUri
- textEmailAddress
- textEmailSubject
- textShortMessage
- textLongMessage
- textPersonName
- textPostalAddress
- textPassword
- textVisiblePassword
- textWebEditText
- textFilter
- textPhonetic
- textWebEmailAddress
- textWebPassword
- number
- numberSigned
- numberDecimal
- numberPassword
- phone
- datetime
- date
- time

You can apparently use one or more of these, separated by a `|` (I've never done this though).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it from XML, but EditTextpreference [exposes the EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#getEditText()) so you can do it programmatically. After you load the preferences in your Activity/Fragment, you can do:

```
EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference) PreferenceManager.findPreference("edit");
EditText prefEditText = pref.getEditText();
prefEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
prefEditText.setSingleLine(true);
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AndroidX, to set input type to password for example:

root_preferences.xml:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference
        android:title="Password"
        android:key="my_pref_password"/>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

And in your Setting Fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);


    EditTextPreference pref = findPreference("my_pref_password");
    pref.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
                            InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56755861/8079104)

Basically, you will need to import androidX library and follow my code.

Answer (score 0):

#Simplest and Tested Answer#

***For Only Decimal Value in EditTextPreference***

Write this code in ***onCreatePreferences***

Make sure use both **CLASS** and **Attributes** of that class

Example

InputType.**TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER** | InputType.**TYPE_NUMBER**_FLAG_DECIMAL

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

        EditTextPreference new_bonus= findPreference("new_bonus");
        EditTextPreference old_bonus= findPreference("old_bonus");


        EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener onBindEditTextListener = new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
                editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
            }
        };

        old_bonus.setOnBindEditTextListener(onBindEditTextListener);
        new_bonus.setOnBindEditTextListener(onBindEditTextListener);

    }
}
```