# EditTextPreference not showing numeric keyboard after migrating project to androidx

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx, edittextpreference

After migrating my project to AndroidX using the `Migrate to AndroidX...` functionality provided by Android Studio and having made changes to my dependencies accordingly to have everything running like it is supposed to, I have encountered a minor problem which I haven't been able to resolve.

To set a device number in my application I used an EditTextPreference like the following defined in my `pref_screen.xml` which is set in a PreferenceFragmentCompat class with 
    `setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_screen, string)`:

```
<EditTextPreference
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_perm_device_information_black_24dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:key="change_device_id"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:summary="@string/settings_device_id"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_change_device_id" />
```

It used to show a numeric keyboard to change the value but after migrating to AndroidX it keeps showing a normal keyboard as shown in the image below. I tried changing the inputType and defining the decimals in xml but to no avail. Has something changed to set the inputType for the keyboard after migrating to AndroidX or am I missing something obvious?

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:digits="0123456789"
```

[image: EditTextPreference keyboard]

Comment: try input type as phone once

Comment: Unfortunately it did not change anything

Comment: Currently using a library as a fix for this: https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix

Answer (score 6):

From an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461028/7059947

Cast your Preference to EditTextPreference and use setInputType On Bind.
This saved my day :)

```
            EditTextPreference edpPrefernce = (EditTextPreference) pPreference;

            edpPrefernce.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {

                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                }
            });
```

Comment: If some one needs number decimal then use like this `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`

Answer (score 1):

Google has not fixed this yet. You can use takisoft's fix for this problem:

https://bintray.com/takisoft/android/com.takisoft.preferencex%3Apreferencex/1.0.0

Add to `build.gradle` (project):

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/takisoft/android"
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Add to `build.gradle` (app module):

```
implementation 'com.takisoft.preferencex:preferencex:1.0.0'
```

Change the imports in your classes and the components in your XML resources:

```
androidx.preference.EditTextPreference -> com.takisoft.preferencex.EditTextPreference
androidx.preference.PreferenceCategory -> com.takisoft.preferencex.PreferenceCategory
androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat -> com.takisoft.preferencex.PreferenceFragmentCompat
```

In your `PreferenceFragmentCompat` subclass, change the `onCreatePreferences(...)` declaration to `onCreatePreferencesFix(...)`.

... and voila! The old parameters, like `numeric` and `singleLine` will be back and work!

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

Add to `build.gradle` (app module):

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Comment: How do you specify the inputType with androidx from XML?